# C++ program debug heIp

Tags: c++, debugging

**Problem is**:
Mr. Chef has been given a number N. He has a tendency to double whatever he get. So now he has got the number N with him and he has multiplied the number N by 2. Now Chef is superstitious. He believes in something known as Lucky Number. His lucky number is defined as any number, which
when multiplied by 2 has no other factors other than 1,2, and N. If the number is lucky all you have to do is print “LUCKY NUMBER”. If the number is not a lucky number, print “Sorry”..
Input

The first line consists of T, which is the number of test cases. Every line of the next T lines consists of N.
Output

Print LUCKY NUMBER if the number is lucky and “Sorry” if the number is not lucky followed by a new line.
Constraints

1<=T<=1000

1<=N<=1000000

Input

3

26

12

11

Output:

Sorry

Sorry

LUCKY NUMBER

**My Program**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
   int x;
   string l;
   cout << "Input Number Codechef.." << endl; 
   cin>>x;
   COND:
   if ((x*2)%1 = 0 && (x*2)%2 = 0 && (x*2)%3 != 0)
   {

       l = "LUCKY NUMBER";
       cout<<l;
       else
       {
       l = "sorry";
       cout<<l;

       }


   }
   if (l = "LUCKY NUMBER")
   {
       break;
       else
       {
          goto COND;  
       }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have to use `==` when comparing, not `=`

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Your compiler should give you a whole bunch of errors to fix. Is there any specific error or problem you need help with? We will not write your homework/assignment for you.

Answer (score 1):

When comparing data, one should use `==` and not `=` because one equation sign means assignment and two of them mean testing for equality.

`l="hello";` assigns the value `"hello"` to the variable `l` while `l=="hello"` returns true (1) when `l` is equal to `"hello"` and false (0) when it is not.

That means, `l="hello"` will *always* result in true.

Moreover, you seem to have a bug in logic (and in code) here:

```
if (l = "LUCKY NUMBER")
{
   break;
   else
   {
      goto COND;  
   }
}
```

You want to write like this:

```
if (l == "LUCKY NUMBER") break;
else goto COND;
```

The same happens here

```
if ((x*2)%1 = 0 && (x*2)%2 = 0 && (x*2)%3 != 0)
{
   l = "LUCKY NUMBER";
   cout<<l;
   else
   {
   l = "sorry";
   cout<<l;

   }
}
```

You need this instead:

```
if (((x*2)%1 == 0) && ((x*2)%2 == 0) && ((x*2)%3 != 0))
l = "LUCKY NUMBER";
else l = "sorry";

cout<<l;
```